# There must be a better way to get the mean, median of this list of dicts

Tags: python, lambda, python-itertools

I have a list of measurements, and the count of items matching that measurement. Something like this:

```
MYDATA = [{"Length": 6, "Count": 2},
        {"Length": 7, "Count": 3},
        {"Length": 8, "Count": 3},
        {"Length": 9, "Count": 3},
        {"Length": 10, "Count": 7},
        {"Length": 11, "Count": 2}]
```

I need the mean and median of that list. I know I can use some `for` loops and `if` statements to get at both:

```
def get_mean(data):
    """ given a list of dicts with keys 'Length' and 'Count' calculate the mean
    length"""
    total_len = 0
    total_count = sum([d['Count'] for d in data])
    for row in data:
        total_len = total_len + (row['Length'] * row['Count'])
    mean = total_len / total_count
    return mean


def get_median(data):
    """ given a list of dicts with keys 'Length' and 'Count' calculate median
    length"""
    sub_count = 0
    total_count = sum([d['Count'] for d in data])
    for row in data:
        sub_count = sub_count + row['Count']
        if sub_count < (total_count / 2):
            print '%s leaves %scm or less: not quite half.' % (sub_count, row['Length'])
        elif 'median' in locals():
            print 'We already found the median.'
        else:
            print '%scm, subtotal %s' % (row['Length'], sub_count)
            median = row['Length']
    return median
```

But both seem clunky. I have a sneaking suspicion I could do this in one line if I understood `lambda` and `itertools` better, so I'm wondering if anyone has suggestions for how I'd do that?

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Do you care about the code length or efficiency? If the latter, can you change the initial data structure?

Comment: there is [`statistics` module in stdlib since Python 3.4](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/statistics.html)

Comment: @Aशwiniचhaudhary I had no idea. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Easily done using [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(MYDATA)

mean = (df.Length * df.Count).sum() / float(df.Count.sum())

total_count = df.Count.sum()
median_idx = np.argmin(abs(df.Count.cumsum() - total_count/2.))
median = df.Length[median_idx]
```

(The median is the element whose "rank" is closest to the "middle index", i.e. `total_count/2`. The ranks are computed using `cumsum`)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = [{"Length": 6, "Count": 2},
        {"Length": 7, "Count": 3},
        {"Length": 8, "Count": 3},
        {"Length": 9, "Count": 3},
        {"Length": 10, "Count": 7},
        {"Length": 11, "Count": 2}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
# the code below is borrowed from shx2's answer
mean = (df.Length * df.Count).sum() / float(df.Count.sum())

total_count = df.Count.sum()
median_idx = np.argmin(abs(df.Count.cumsum() - total_count/2.))
median = df.Length[median_idx]
```

Alternatively, you could de-aggregate your data to make the calculations easier:

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import chain

data = [{"Length": 6, "Count": 2},
        {"Length": 7, "Count": 3},
        {"Length": 8, "Count": 3},
        {"Length": 9, "Count": 3},
        {"Length": 10, "Count": 7},
        {"Length": 11, "Count": 2}]

deaggregated = list(chain(*[i['Count'] * [i['Length']] for i in data]))

df = pd.DataFrame({'Length': deaggregated})

print df.Length.mean()
print df.Length.median()
```

Comment: As I understand it, OP is looking for weighted mean and median, where the weights are the counts

Comment: Uh, you're right. I see that you've provided the answer in the meantime. I am borrowing your code and upvoting your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write new `mean`, `median` functions for every new datastructure that your program might have. Adapt your input to a generic `mean`, `median` functions instead e.g.:

```
L = [d["Length"] for d in MYDATA for _ in range(d["Count"])]
mean_mydata = mean(L)
median_mydata = median(L)
```

where `mean`, `median` are generic functions such as defined in [`statistics` module](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/statistics.html).

It is not as efficient as it could be but don't optimize unless you need it.

Comment: based on his code though, he's using Python 2 and `statistics` is not available.

Comment: @isedev: yes, that is why I said "such as". The source code is linked in the docs

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of writing unreadable one-liners (sorry mom, sorry dad)

```
#! python
import operator as op
import itertools as it
data = [{"Length": 6, "Count": 2},
        {"Length": 7, "Count": 3},
        {"Length": 8, "Count": 3},
        {"Length": 9, "Count": 3},
        {"Length": 10, "Count": 7},
        {"Length": 11, "Count": 2}]
lengths = map(op.itemgetter('Length'), data)
counts = map(op.itemgetter('Count'), data)

# Here be dragons, these are freaking ugly expressions, do not ever write them.

# This one is easy, imap(op.mul,x,y) is even hinted in itertools doc
mean_length = sum(it.imap(op.mul, lengths, counts)) / float(sum(counts))

# That one is a silly beast. Have fun trying to understand it :D    
median_length = reduce(lambda a,i: a if a[2] else (i[0], a[1]+i[1], a[1]+i[1]>=sum(counts)/2.), it.izip(lengths, counts), (None, 0, False))[0]
```